How to disable js logging when using QWebEngineView
I am using QWebEngineView in my pyqt app. I am navigating to tradingview website and it is logging lots of errors continuously. This is making it difficult to find my logs in the mix. How can I stop the js logs to appear in Terminal? E.g. logs -
s: 2024-06-29T15:31:46.819Z:Fetch:GET https://s3.tradingview.com/conversions_en.json. TypeError: Failed to fetch
js: 2024-06-29T15:31:46.820Z:Chart.ChartModel:An error occurred while getting currencies config: TypeError: Failed to fetch
js: 2024-06-29T15:31:46.820Z:Chart.ChartModel:An error occurred while getting units config: TypeError: Failed to fetch
js: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e.replaceChildren is not a function
js: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e.replaceChildren is not a function
js: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e.replaceChildren is not a function

